# bash find xargs grep only single occurence

Tags: bash, find, grep, xargs

Maybe it's a bit strange - and maybe there are other tools to do this but, well..

I am using the following classic bash command to find all files which contain some string:

```
find . -type f | xargs grep "something"
```

I have a great number of files, on multiple depths. first occurrence of "something" is enough for me, but find continues searching, and takes a long time to complete the rest of the files. What I would like to do is something like a "feedback" from grep back to find so that find could stop searching for more files. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply keep it within the realm of find:

```
find . -type f -exec grep "something" {} \; -quit
```

This is how it works:

The `-exec` will work when the `-type f` will be true. And because `grep` returns `0` (success/true) when the `-exec grep "something"` has a match, the `-quit` will be triggered.

Answer (score 8):

```
find -type f | xargs grep e | head -1
```

does exactly that: when the `head` terminates, the middle element of the pipe is notified with a 'broken pipe' signal, terminates in turn, and notifies the `find`. You should see a notice such as

```
xargs: grep: terminated by signal 13
```

which confirms this.

Comment: +1 for explanation and the alternative, though the other answer seems more elegant to me, since it is more self-sufficient

Answer (score 8):

To do this without changing tools: (I love xargs)

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f |
    # xargs -n20 -P20: use 10 parallel processes to grep files in batches of 20
    # grep -m1: show just on match per file
    # grep --line-buffered: multiple matches from independent grep processes
    #      will not be interleaved
    xargs -P10 -n20 grep -m1 --line-buffered "$1" 2> >(
        # Error output (stderr) is redirected to this command.
        # We ignore this particular error, and send any others back to stderr.
        grep -v '^xargs: .*: terminated by signal 13$' >&2
    ) |
    # Little known fact: all `head` does is send signal 13 after n lines.
    head -n 1
```

Comment: +1 never knew xargs would have such multitasking capabilities - thanks for other comments as well! :)